# How to Avoid Celery Truncated "task_args" Text in "django_celery_results_taskresult"

Tags: python, json, asynchronous, celery, django-celery

In my Django project, I am using Celery to asynchronously run my tasks.

The problem I am facing is that the "`task_args`" column in "`django_celery_results_taskresult`" is truncated (i.e., text followed by ellipsis).

For example, I am expecting the entire "`process_4_items`" value in "`task_args`." However, that is not the case. I can see the same truncated text in the command prompt of the Celery worker in execution (see below "`[CELERY WORKER COMMAND PROMPT FOR ONE ITERATION]`").

I really am not sure what I need to do to get the entire "`process_4_items`" value in "`task_args`."

I am detailing below everything I believe I need to reproduce this item.

Most important, when I debug the project and execute line by line, the entire content of "`process_4_items`" value appears in "`task_args`."

##### `[celeryconfig.py]`

> `broker_url = 'amqp://localhost:5672//'`
>
> `imports = ('operation_hawkeye.tasks',)`
>
> `result_backend = 'django-db'`
>
> `accept_content = ['json']`
>
> `task_always_eager = False`

##### `[views.py]`

> `from celery import group`
>
> `process_4_items = [`
>
> `{`
>
> `"service_id": "7f7962b082cb8da55e01f4f013d8fefbc97948ec03400c93423b050d",`
>
> `"service_id_unique": "c30ed891987f4d8d3debcaef7edb0f582e6b634f1ebed00fb88f0ec7",`
>
> `"service_type": "buzz_collect_compare",`
>
> `"service_file_pf_folder": "",`
>
> `"service_file_nanonsportsproductivity_folder": "",`
>
> `"service_file_tba_report": "",`
>
> `"service_file_buzz_collect_compare": "services/buzzcollect_xml_compare/2021/06/01/file_2_name_Update_COOKINGHD_May_2021_Listin_yWoWXo1.xml",`
>
> `"service_file_type": "XML 1.0 document, ASCII text",`
>
> `"service_file_name": "file_2_name_Update_COOKINGHD_May 2021 Listings(4-26-21 thru 5-30-21).xml",`
>
> `"service_file_size": 396557,`
>
> `"service_status": "In Queue for Upload",`
>
> `"service_status_remarks": {`
>
> `"source_information": {`
>
> `"source_id": "5191",`
>
> `"source_name": "10NEWS2",`
>
> `"file_1_name": "Original_COOKINGHD_May 2021 Listings(4-26-21 thru 5-30-21).xml",`
>
> `"file_2_name": "Update_COOKINGHD_May 2021 Listings(4-26-21 thru 5-30-21).xml"`
>
> `}`
>
> `},`
>
> `"service_creation_date": "2021-06-01T18:18:40.968Z",`
>
> `"service_owner": "p.premlal@spi-global.com"`
>
> `},`
>
> `{`
>
> `"service_id": "7f7962b082cb8da55e01f4f013d8fefbc97948ec03400c93423b050d",`
>
> `"service_id_unique": "2edaf2535945992d13b9ee85e908b21cbd520a02642bd7faf7f229bc",`
>
> `"service_type": "buzz_collect_compare",`
>
> `"service_file_pf_folder": "",`
>
> `"service_file_nanonsportsproductivity_folder": "",`
>
> `"service_file_tba_report": "",`
>
> `"service_file_buzz_collect_compare": "services/buzzcollect_xml_compare/2021/06/01/file_1_name_Original_COOKINGHD_May_2021_List_P2PlYY7.xml",`
>
> `"service_file_type": "XML 1.0 document, ASCII text",`
>
> `"service_file_name": "file_1_name_Original_COOKINGHD_May 2021 Listings(4-26-21 thru 5-30-21).xml",`
>
> `"service_file_size": 396409,`
>
> `"service_status": "In Queue for Upload",`
>
> `"service_status_remarks": {`
>
> `"source_information": {`
>
> `"source_id": "5191",`
>
> `"source_name": "10NEWS2",`
>
> `"file_1_name": "Original_COOKINGHD_May 2021 Listings(4-26-21 thru 5-30-21).xml",`
>
> `"file_2_name": "Update_COOKINGHD_May 2021 Listings(4-26-21 thru 5-30-21).xml"`
>
> `}`
>
> `},`
>
> `"service_creation_date": "2021-06-01T18:18:40.935Z",`
>
> `"service_owner": "p.premlal@spi-global.com"`
>
> `}`
>
> `]`
>
> `jobs_4 = group(tasks.buzz_collect_compare_main.s(process_4_items))`
>
> `result_4 = jobs_4.apply_async()`

#### `[tasks.py]`

> `@app.task(bind=True)`
>
> `def buzz_collect_compare_main(self, items):`
>
> `process_items = items`
>
> `...`

#### `[CELERY WORKER COMMAND PROMPT FOR ONE ITERATION]`

> `[2021-06-01 09:37:29,972: DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-32] (0.010)`
>
> `UPDATE`
>
> `"django_celery_results_taskresult"`
>
> `SET`
>
> `"task_id" = 'daca83c1-3297-4e64-8a5e-f4b61aef84e2',`
>
> `"task_name" = 'operation_hawkeye.tasks.buzz_collect_compare_main',`
>
> `"task_args" = '([{''service_id'': ''dc30fc45948975044cb00c39a4d5a0db8e28bc34f0b4d52fd4dcddef'', ''service_id_unique'': ''2004e35ae5dcc2586ae5fca16ab8a5b2708ffeca233d3bb234feb347'', ''service_type'':  ''buzz_collect_compare'', ''service_file_pf_folder'': '''', ''service_file_nanonsportsproductivity_folder'': '''', ''service_file_tba_report'': '''', ''service_file_buzz_collect_compare'': ''services/buzzcollect_xml_compare/2021/06/01/file_2_name_Update_COOKINGHD_May_2021_Listin_726wZgI.xml'', ''service_file_type'': ''XML 1.0 document, ASCII text'', ''service_file_name'': ''file_2_name_Update_COOKINGHD_May 2021 Listings(4-26-21 thru 5-30-21).xml'', ''service_file_size'': 396557, ''service_status'': ''In Queue for Upload'', ''service_status_remarks'': ''{"source_information": "{\"source_id\": \"27227\", \"source_name\": \"COOKINGHD\", \"file_1_name\": \"Original_COOKINGHD_May 2021 Listings(4-26-21 thru 5-30-21).xml\", \"file_2_name\": \"Update_COOKINGHD_May 2021 Listings(4-26-21 thru 5-30-21).xml\"}"}'', ''service_creation_date'': ''2021-06-01T09:36:56.825Z'', ''service_owner'': ''p...'', ...],)',`
>
> `"task_kwargs" = '{}',`
>
> `"status" = 'PROGRESS',`
>
> `"worker" = 'celery@AMD-RYZEN-UBUNTU',`
>
> `"content_type" = 'application/json',`
>
> `"content_encoding" = 'utf-8',`
>
> `"result" = '{"pending": false, "current": 1254, "total": 1254, "percent": 100.0, "description": "Building row 1254 of 1254"}',`
>
> `"date_created" = '2021-06-01T09:36:58.465884+00:00'::timestamptz,`
>
> `"date_done" = '2021-06-01T09:37:29.962267+00:00'::timestamptz,`
>
> `"traceback" = NULL,`
>
> `"meta" = '{"children": []}'`
>
> `WHERE`
>
> `"django_celery_results_taskresult"."id" = 808;`
>
> `args=('daca83c1-3297-4e64-8a5e-f4b61aef84e2', 'operation_hawkeye.tasks.buzz_collect_compare_main', '([{\'service_id\': \'dc30fc45948975044cb00c39a4d5a0db8e28bc34f0b4d52fd4dcddef\', \'service_id_unique\':  >\'2004e35ae5dcc2586ae5fca16ab8a5b2708ffeca233d3bb234feb347\', \'service_type\': \'buzz_collect_compare\', \'service_file_pf_folder\': \'\', \'service_file_nanonsportsproductivity_folder\': \'\', \'service_file_tba_report\': \'\', \'service_file_buzz_collect_compare\': \'services/buzzcollect_xml_compare/2021/06/01/file_2_name_Update_COOKINGHD_May_2021_Listin_726wZgI.xml\', \'service_file_type\': \'XML 1.0 document, ASCII text\', \'service_file_name\': \'file_2_name_Update_COOKINGHD_May 2021 Listings(4-26-21 thru 5-30-21).xml\', \'service_file_size\': 396557, \'service_status\': \'In Queue for Upload\', \'service_status_remarks\': \'{"source_information": "{\\"source_id\\": \\"27227\\", \\"source_name\\": \\"COOKINGHD\\", \\"file_1_name\\": \\"Original_COOKINGHD_May 2021 Listings(4-26-21 thru 5-30-21).xml\\", \\"file_2_name\\": \\"Update_COOKINGHD_May 2021 Listings(4-26-21 thru 5-30-21).xml\\"}"}\', \'service_creation_date\': \'2021-06-01T09:36:56.825Z\', \'service_owner\': \'p...\', ...],)', '{}', 'PROGRESS', 'celery@AMD-RYZEN-UBUNTU', 'application/json', 'utf-8', '{"pending": false, "current": 1254, "total": 1254, "percent": 100.0, "description": "Building row 1254 of 1254"}', datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 9, 36, 58, 465884, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 9, 37, 29, 962267, tzinfo=<UTC>), '{"children": []}', 808)`

#### `[$ celery -A hawkeye report]`

> `software -> celery:4.4.7 (cliffs) kombu:4.6.11 py:3.8.6`
>
> `billiard:3.6.3.0 py-amqp:2.6.1`
>
> `platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF`
>
> `kernel version:5.8.0-53-generic imp:CPython`
>
> `loader   -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader`
>
> `settings -> transport:amqp results:django-db`
>
> `accept_content: ['json']`
>
> `broker_url: 'amqp://guest:********@localhost:5672//'`
>
> `imports: ('operation_hawkeye.tasks',)`
>
> `result_backend: 'django-db'`
>
> `task_always_eager: False`

## [UPDATE]

Solved this issue by defining the `argsrepr_maxsize` value in `celery.py`. While I had known about this solution earlier, I did not realize that `argsrepr_maxsize` was within `celery.ampq`.

#### `[celery.py]`

> `import os`
>
> `from celery import Celery`
>
> `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'hawkeye.settings')`
>
> `os.environ.setdefault('FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING', '1')`
>
> `app = Celery('hawkeye')`
>
> `default_config = 'hawkeye.celeryconfig'`
>
> `app.config_from_object(default_config)`
>
> `app.amqp.argsrepr_maxsize = 10485760`